# How to clear the field after i set ComboBox value as null?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I have a ComboBox  called projectRequirementComboBox that is dependent from projectComboBox, from where I get the list to show in the dropdown in projectRequirementComboBox, but I want to do something like: when a user changes the project I want to empty projectRequirementComboBox, to be more clear none of the item will not be selected I am doing this right now but still my projectRequirementComboBox  has the old value, I don't know what am I missing .I am using vaadin.version 8.0.7 .

```
private void refreshProjectRequirementCombobox()
{
    List<ProjectRequirement> projectRequirements = new ArrayList<>();
    if (projectComboBox.getValue() != null)
    {
        projectRequirements = projectRequirementService.findCurrentProjectRequirements(projectComboBox.getValue().getProjectId());
    }
    projectRequirementComboBox.setItems(projectRequirements);
    projectRequirementComboBox.setValue(null);

}

private void loadProjectRequirement(Project project)
{
    List<ProjectRequirement> projectRequirements = new ArrayList<>();
    if (project != null)
    {
        projectRequirements = projectRequirementService.findCurrentProjectRequirements(project.getProjectId());
    }
    projectRequirementComboBox.setItems(projectRequirements);
}
```

I call refreshProjectRequirementCombobox here.

```
 projectComboBox.addValueChangeListener(event ->
            {
                refreshProjectRequirementCombobox();
                loadRejectReason();
            });
```

Comment: What version of Vaadin are you using?

Comment: I am using 8.0.7 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this should work. I created a minimum example with two ComboBoxes "main" and "dependent". The selection of the dependent ComboBox depends on the selection of the main ComboBox. Therefore there is a ValueChangeListener on the main ComboBox that resets the items and the selected value of the dependent ComboBox. When you start the application you see that the offered items of the dependent ComboBox change and that none of these new items is selected.

I think you have to post more of your code (where do you call `refreshProjectRequirementCombobox` from?) to see what you are doing different.

Here is my example minimum project code:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    final ComboBox<String> main = new ComboBox<>();
    final ComboBox<String> dependent = new ComboBox<>();
    final Map<String, String[]> dependentsByMain = new HashMap<>();
    dependentsByMain.put("A", new String[]{"AA", "AB", "AC"});
    dependentsByMain.put("B", new String[]{"BA", "BB", "BC"});
    dependentsByMain.put("C", new String[]{"CA", "CB", "CC"});

    List<String> mainItems = new ArrayList<>(dependentsByMain.keySet());
    main.setItems(mainItems);
    dependent.setItems(Arrays.asList("Test1", "Test2", "Test3"));
    dependent.setValue("Test1");
    main.addValueChangeListener((HasValue.ValueChangeListener<String>) valueChangeEvent -> {
        if (valueChangeEvent.getValue() != null) {
            dependent.setItems(dependentsByMain.get(valueChangeEvent.getValue()));
            dependent.setValue(null);
        }
    });
    layout.addComponents(main, dependent);
    setContent(layout);
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Have a look at Srinivasan Sekar's answer and its comments. This is a bug in the used version (8.0.7) which seems to be fixed in version 8.5 (according to https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/9047#issuecomment-437864866). I tried my example code with version 8.7.1 so it works. With version 8.0.7 it doesn't.

So the main solution is to update the used Vaadin version. As a workaround (when unable to upgrade the Vaadin version) you FIRST have to set the ComboBox's value to null and THEN set the new items. So in my example the ValueChangeListener must look like:

```
main.addValueChangeListener((HasValue.ValueChangeListener<String>) valueChangeEvent -> {
    if (valueChangeEvent.getValue() != null) {
        dependent.setValue(null);
        dependent.setItems(dependentsByMain.get(valueChangeEvent.getValue())); 
    }
});
```

Comment: , i have  listener also will post more code cause this, doesn't help much but ,thanks a lot , trying means a lot

Comment: yeah I tried that but in my case didn't clean the field, did yours worked?

Comment: Did you already try updating to a Vaadin version >= 8.5, too? Updating the version worked for me and switching both lines in the ValueChangeListener worked for me, too. The workaround to first set the value to null and then set the new items is described here: https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/9047#issue-220575873

Comment: I had to add setValue(null); even at load and now works, but I don't understand why is working ?

Comment: I would actually recommend to update to Vaadin 8.8.2 since in version 8.8.0 had bunch of fixes to ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

There is open issue in Vaadin  https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/9566 which refers to https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/2813

Going through the issue I found that by creating a custom combobox you can fix the issue:

```
public class ClearableComboBox<T> extends ComboBox<T> {
    public ClearableComboBox(String in) {
        super(in);
    }
    
    protected void setSelectedFromServer(T item) {
        String key = itemToKey(item);

        T oldSelection = getSelectedItem().orElse(getEmptyValue());
        doSetSelectedKey(key);

        fireEvent(new SingleSelectionEvent<>(ClearableComboBox.this, oldSelection, false));
    }       
}
```

Additionally, make sure to call `setValue` before calling `setItems` to clear items.

```
cmb.setValue(null);
cmb.setItems(aEmptyCollection);
```

Comment: This is absolutely the problem! The code from my answer was tested with Vaadin 8.7.1. If I downgrade to 8.0.7 it behaves like it is described in the question. Maybe it is enough to upgrade your Vaadin version? According to https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/9047 this was fixed in Vaadin 8.5.

Comment: I don't really understand this solution, can you explain a bit more, I apologize for that

Comment: There is a bug in your Vaadin version (8.0.7) that prevents the ComboBox's value to be cleared when new Items where set. You have two options: Upgrade your vaadin version to >= 8.5 or if you are not able to update the version: in `refreshProjectRequirementCombobox` put the line  `projectRequirementComboBox.setValue(null);` BEFORE `projectRequirementComboBox.setItems(projectRequirements);` as a workaround.

Comment: You still have the option to try Srinivasan Sekar's solution (I didn't try). Create a class like he described in his answer and then use `ClearableComboBox` isntead of `ComboBox` for your ComboBoxes `projectRequirementComboBox` and `projectComboBox` (so the variable declarations look like `ClearableComboBox<Entity> projectComboBox = new ClearableComboBox<>();`)

Comment: was going to add the same , was busy with my work. Thanks. @codinghaus